# Making the URL short in the address bar when a button clicked in php

Tags: php, apache2

I'm working on my website in PHP, and I want to make the URLs simpler. Currently, I use the easy solution of putting the post id in the url:

**[example.com/ReadPost.php?id=42](http://example.com/ReadPost.php?id=42)**

But to remember again I found a way here by creating .htaccess file and store it inside my directory, so when i just clicked, it's still the same URL like above.

I want my URL to be in this form:

**[example.com/ReadPost/42](http://example.com/ReadPost/42)**

Without actually having to create a new directory under ReadPost/ every time.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Posts/([0-9]+)/?$
ReadPost.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

For example. http://kerbalx.com has a page for every user, but doesn't do `/user/?u=ThisIsAnExample`, it does `/ThisIsAnExample/`

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Contents of your htaccess file?

Comment: @ildflue This is the content of my .htaccess file                                                                                                                         
                                                                                              
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^Posts/([0-9]+)/?$    ReadPost.php?id=$1    [NC,L]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /DevelopMinds/    
RewriteRule ^ReadPost/2$ ReadPost.php?id=2 [L]
```

To make it work generally, for any post id, use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /DevelopMinds/
RewriteRule ^ReadPost/(\d+)$ ReadPost.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It is work like i said, but i need when i click on the button or post title the url automatically be http://localhost/DevelopMinds/ReadPost/id_number

Comment: Then use something on the order of `<a href="/DevelopMinds/ReadPost/42>Foo bar baz</a>"`

Comment: And by the way, when the page displayed, it is without any formatting or styling, i mean it looks like without CSS file :(

Comment: @Blacksilver Ok i will do that in my index.php and try to put the name of the directory before the name of the file ReadPost

Comment: It doesn't change in the address bar when i clicked on the post title. :(

Comment: try actually typing `http://localhost/DevelopMinds/ReadPost/2` into your url bar, what happens?

Comment: Yes it working as i told you, but i need it to be changed in the address bar automatically to this http://localhost/DevelopMinds/ReadPost/2

Comment: With that Rewrite rule, Apache can't tell the difference between `/DevelopMinds/ReadPost/2` and `/DevelopMinds/ReadPost.php?id=2`; It doesn't know to redirect from the latter to the former.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163661/discussion-between-ali-sattar-and-blacksilver).

Comment: Any help please??

Comment: I just knew that is cannot be automatically like i was thinking yesterday, but in case of an external server if this will work and the URL changes automatically?